# hsqldb - "Could not load properties from file" on ubuntu

Tags: hsqldb

I'm trying to run hsqldb on ubuntu. I changed the runServer.bat to runServer.sh.

original runServer.bat:

```
cd ..\data 
@java -classpath ../lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

my runServer.sh:

```
java -classpath /home/msk5804/portal/hsqldb-2.2.5/hsqldb/lib/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

I originally kept the cd ../data but that caused problems. 
 So instead I put the server.properties file in the bin directory as the runServer.sh.

However, org.hsqldb.server.Server still can't find the server.properties file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The server.properties file should be located in the home directory of the user that starts the server. The command to start the server is issued from this directory. This is detailed in the Guide:

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/unix-chapt.html#unix_cat_setup-sect